# Web application running slow after updating to Php 8.x

Tags: apache, odbc, wamp

We are trying to deploy a new web server (WAMP 32bit) with PHP 8.x and Apache 2.4.57 on Windows Server 2019. Data stored in a MSSQL server 2012 which is running on a Windows 2012 R2. On this environment PHP pages 10 times slower or not loading at all (timeout).

Current web server is running on Windows Server 2019, WAMP 32bit, PHP 7.4, Apache 2.4.54 and connecting to same database.

For testing purpose, we removed anti-virus and disabled firewall to rule out any security checks.

We are not sure where to start as the system does not give any error message despite PHP error level set to E_ALL.